# c# calling function from the main form in a childform isn't working

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am stuck between a rock and hard place right now.

I have my childform called and docked into the contentspanel under the main form.
After the async timer I close the first childform and call a function from the main form to display the next child form but nothing works.

This is the function in the mainform I want to call

```
public void ShowMainMenu()
    {
        FormMainMenu MM = new FormMainMenu();
        OpenChildForm(MM, new object());
    }
```

This is the function in the childform that is meant to close the first child form which is does but then call the above function, to show the next child form.

(They are commented out for you can notice the function line)

```
public async Task DisplayMainMenu(int interval)
    {
        await Task.Delay(interval);
        this.Close();

        //FormMainBuild MB = new FormMainBuild();
        //MB.ShowMainMenu();
    }
```

Please help, I have searched online for hours, tried multiple fixes and nothing is allowing me to call the ShowMainMenu function from my parent form.

(All childforms are docked under a panel control in the mainform)

Comment: Whenever you call _new FormMainBuild()_ you create a new _instance_ of FormMainBuild. Then you execute a call against this instance not against the instance already created and on screen. You need a reference to the current FormMainBuild instance to ask it to execute the method.

Comment: Thanks @Steve and how would I do that? Im sitting here twiddling my thumbs atm

Comment: This is an [X Y Problem](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/12/26/us/politics/dr-oz-medical-advice.html).  Please tell us what you're trying to accomplish, rather than asking us to try and fix your broken solution..

Comment: I explained my situation above. I have my MainForm that houses the childforms and docks them to a panel in the MainForm.

When the timer under the loading form is finished, i want to call a function from the mainform.

This will in return display the second child form

Comment: Are you making some kind of a timed quiz? the user gets up to e.g. 45 seconds to answer a question on the child form, if they close the child form early, great, if not it closes after 45 seconds regardless?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to accomplish what I understand you to be trying to accomplish I use the event pattern.

In your child form you would want an event to be called after your delay:

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler OnWaitCompleted;

    public ChildForm(int interval)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WaitTime(interval);
    }

    public void WaitTime(int interval)
    {
        Task.Delay(interval).ContinueWith((MethodInvoker) =>
        {
            OnWaitCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your parent form you would setup your event handling action before you display the child form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSpawnChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm cf = new ChildForm(5000);

        cf.OnWaitCompleted += (obj, args) =>
        {
            LoadNextChild();
        };

        cf.Show(this);
    }

    private void LoadNextChild()
    {

    }
}
```

I think this method is better as it avoids having child forms trying to control the content of their parent, which should be the responsibility of the parent.